# No window previews in Ubuntu MATE 18.04?

Tags: compiz, 18.04, ubuntu-mate

I've installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and want to get the thumbnail window previews when hovering over applications in the bottom panel.  The option appears to be on:

[image]

I *seem* to get a flash of what might be a preview for a fraction of a second on an initial hover sometimes but it's really hard to tell as it disappears more or less immediately when it happens.

How should I go about debugging/fixing this?